# How can I append pandas data frames to CSV files COLUMN-WISE?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am pre-processing a large dataset with 840.000 samples and more than 400 features. I need to store dataframes in single csv files to reduce memory. THEREFORE, I should avoid pd.concat since it takes loads of memory

I have different dataframes, depending on the nature of the variables. How can I append CSV files by columns? It seems that:

```
df_1.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
df_2.to_csv('file.csv', mode='a', index=False)
df_3.to_csv('file.csv', mode='a', index=False)
```

Creates the file file.csv, and then append df_2, and df_3 just below each other. How can I append it by columns and not by rows?

EXAMPLE:

```
DF1

row1:    variable_a variable_b
row2:       0            1
row3:       1            1
row839999:  0            1
```

DF2:

```
row1:    variable_c variable_d
row2:       0            1
row3:       1            1
row839999:  0            1
```

FINAL DF

```
row1:    variable_a variable_b variable_c variable_d
row2:       0            1         0        1
row3:       1            1         1        1 
row839999:  0            1         0        1
```

Comment: Use pd.concat with axis = 1, for https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html

Comment: The title of your problem is confusing. Vertically logically means one below the other, Adding column wise sounds more like horizontally

Comment: what do you mean appending by columns? can you show an example?

Comment: You need to read the csv file into dataframe first then use concat with axis=1 to append it and finally write it back to csv file.

Comment: I edited the title, I cannot use pd.concat since it takes too much memory

Comment: If you don't want to read the csv then from beginning you have to store the dataframe in transposed way so that you can keep appending it, look at 
 [pandas.DataFrame.transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html).

Comment: you may need to look at some other options here. if you're running out of memory that can be expected as you have 3 dataframes with 840,000 X 400 features. have you tried concat? have you tried writing with the csv module and just looping through the records?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a database, you should use SQL to merge and use pandas read_sql to read in what’s needed. Alternatively, you can look at Dask (https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/139). I don’t have experience with it, just pointing you to the resources that might be useful.

Dask DataFrame is a large parallel dataframe composed of many smaller Pandas dataframes, split along the index. That might solve your problem of MemoryError. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to convert the types of the variables. First, the variables were int32 and I converted to int8. Then it did not take that much time.